# Orthochronous Lorentz transformations are time-preserving and $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: special-relativity, differential-geometry, group-theory, representation-theory, topology

Let's consider the pseudosphere/[hyperboloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid) in $\mathbb{R}^{1,2}$ given by

$$x^2+y^2-z^2=-R^2.$$

We know that the [Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group)

$$O(1,2)=\{ A \in {\rm Mat}(3,\mathbb{R}): A^tGA=G \},$$

where $G={\rm diag}(-1,-1,1)$ leaves the pseudosphere invariant. Now we are interested in the following facts:

1. How can we show that the orthochronous Lorentz group $O_+(1,2)=\{ A: a_{33}>0 \}$ is subgroup and, more important, maps upper cone to upper cone?
2. What is the relation between groups $O_+(1,2)$ and $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: To help you start: for 1.) you will first of all need to show that if $g,h \in O_+$, then $g^{-1}$ and $g \cdot h$ are also in $O_+.$ This requires some algebra.

Answer (score 8):

I) The proof that the orthochronous [Lorentz group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) $O^{+}(1,d; \mathbb{R})$ form a group (which is closed/stabile under multiplication and inversion) is given in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36384/2451) Phys.SE post.

II) Next we would like to prove the following.

> *Proposition.* A [Lorentz transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation) takes a timelike vector 
>   $\tilde{x}=\begin{bmatrix} x^0\cr x \end{bmatrix}$ 
>   with $|x| < |x^0|$ to a timelike vector 
>   $\tilde{x}^{\prime}=\begin{bmatrix}x^{\prime 0}\cr x^{\prime}\end{bmatrix}$
>   with $|x^{\prime}| < |x^{\prime 0}|$.

*Proof.* This follows from the fact that a Lorentz transformation preserves the Minkowski norm. $\Box$

> *Proposition.* An orthochronous Lorentz transformation takes a future timelike vector $\tilde{x}=\begin{bmatrix} x^0\cr x \end{bmatrix}$ 
>   with $|x| < x^0$ to a future timelike vector 
>   $\tilde{x}^{\prime}=\begin{bmatrix}x^{\prime 0}\cr x^{\prime}\end{bmatrix}$ with $|x^{\prime}| < x^{\prime 0}$.

*Proof.* To prove that an orthochronous Lorentz transformation

$$\tag{1} \tilde{x}^{\prime}~=~\Lambda\tilde{x}, \qquad 
\Lambda ~=~ \begin{bmatrix}a & b^t \cr c &R \end{bmatrix}~\in~O(1,d; \mathbb{R}), $$

(which by definition has $a=\Lambda^0{}_0>0$), takes a future timelike vector $\tilde{x}=\begin{bmatrix} x^0\cr x \end{bmatrix}$ with

$$\tag{2} |x| ~<~ x^0$$

to a future timelike vector 
$\tilde{x}^{\prime}=\begin{bmatrix}x^{\prime 0}\cr x^{\prime}\end{bmatrix}$ with $|x^{\prime}| < x^{\prime 0}$, it is enough to prove that

$$\tag{3}  0~\stackrel{(4)}{<}~  a x^0 + b\cdot x~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~ x^{\prime 0}.$$

But the inequality (3) follows from the following inequality

$$\tag{4}  -2\frac{b}{a} \cdot \frac{x}{x^0}~\leq~ \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^2 +\left(\frac{x}{x^0}\right)^2 ~\stackrel{(2)}{<}~  \frac{a^2-1}{a^2} + 1 ~<~2. $$

Here we used the fact that $ b\cdot b =a^2-1$ and the inequality (2). $\Box$

III) Thus there only remains OP's last question:

> What is the relation between $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $SO^{+}(1,2;\mathbb{R})$?

Naturally our treatment will have some overlap with Trimok's correct answer. We use the sign convention $(+,-,-,-)$ for the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$.

IV) First let us identify the Minkowski space $M(1,3;\mathbb{R})$ with the space of Hermitian  $2\times2$ matrices $u(2)$. In detail, there is a bijective isometry from the Minkowski space $(M(1,3;\mathbb{R}),||\cdot||^2)$ to the space of  Hermitian $2\times2$ matrices $(u(2),\det(\cdot))$,
$$\mathbb{R}^4~=~M(1,3;\mathbb{R})  ~\cong ~  u(2)
~:=~\{\sigma\in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{C}) \mid \sigma^{\dagger}=\sigma \} 
~=~ {\rm span}_{\mathbb{R}} \{\sigma_{\mu} \mid \mu=0,1,2,3\},  $$ 
$$ M(1,3;\mathbb{R})\ni\tilde{x}~=~(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3) \quad\mapsto \quad\sigma~=~x^{\mu}\sigma_{\mu}~\in~ u(2), $$ 
$$\tag{5}  ||\tilde{x}||^2 ~=~x^{\mu} \eta_{\mu\nu}x^{\nu} ~=~\det(\sigma), \qquad \sigma_{0}~:=~{\bf 1}_{2 \times 2},$$

see also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28505/2451) Phys.SE post.

V) There is a [group action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) $\rho: SL(2,\mathbb{C})\times u(2) \to u(2)$ given by

$$\tag{6} g\quad \mapsto\quad\rho(g)\sigma~:= ~g\sigma g^{\dagger},
\qquad g\in SL(2,\mathbb{C}),\qquad\sigma\in u(2). $$

A straightforward calculation shows that the two groups [$SL(2,\mathbb{R}) \equiv Sp(2,\mathbb{R})$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2%28R%29) and

$$SU(1,1)~=~\left\{\left. \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b^{*} & a^{*}  \end{bmatrix}\right|  a,b\in \mathbb{C}, |a|^2-|b|^2=1\right\}$$
$$ \tag{7} ~=~\left\{\left. \begin{bmatrix} f\sqrt{|b|^2+1} & b \\ b^{*} & f^{*}\sqrt{|b|^2+1}   \end{bmatrix} \right|  f,b\in \mathbb{C}, |f|=1\right\}~\cong~S^1\times \mathbb{C}$$

are the stabilizer subgroups (also called the isotropy subgroups) of the $x^2$-coordinate and the $x^3$-coordinate, respectively. Since there is no spatially preferred  direction, the two subgroups are isomorphic. (The explicit isomorphism is given in Ref. 1.) The two subgroups are path connected but not simply connected. In detail, the [fundamental group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_group) is

$$\tag{8} \pi_1(SL(2,\mathbb{R}),*)~=~\pi_1(SU(1,1),*)~=~\pi_1(S^1\times \mathbb{C},*)$$
$$~=~\pi_1(S^1,*)\oplus \pi_1(\mathbb{C},*)~=~\mathbb{Z}.$$

VI) We now restrict attention to the $1+2$ dimensional case. Let us identity the Minkowski space $M(1,2;\mathbb{R})~\subseteq~ M(1,3;\mathbb{R})$ as the hyperplane $x^2=0$. The corresponding hyperplane in $u(2)$ is the set

$$\tag{9} s(2)~:=~\{ \sigma \in {\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \mid \sigma^t =\sigma \}  $$

of real symmetric $2\times2 $ matrices.

VII) There is a group action $\rho: SL(2,\mathbb{R})\times s(2) \to s(2)$ given by

$$\tag{10} g\quad \mapsto\quad\rho(g)\sigma~:= ~g\sigma g^t,
\qquad g\in SL(2,\mathbb{R}),\qquad\sigma\in s(2), $$

which is length preserving, i.e. $g$ is a pseudo-orthogonal (or Lorentz) transformation. In other words, there is a [Lie group homomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group_homomorphism)

$$\tag{11} \rho: SL(2,\mathbb{R}) \quad\to\quad O(s(2),\mathbb{R})~\cong~ O(1,2;\mathbb{R}).$$

Since $\rho$ is a continuous map from a path connected set $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, the image $\rho(SL(2,\mathbb{R}))$ is also path connected. We conclude that 
Lie group homomorphism

$$\tag{12} \rho: SL(2,\mathbb{R}) \quad\to\quad SO^{+}(s(2),\mathbb{R})~\cong~ SO^{+}(1,2;\mathbb{R})$$

maps into the restricted [Lorentz group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) $SO^{+}(1,2;\mathbb{R})$. [Here we have used the easily established fact that the Lorentz group $O(1,2;\mathbb{R})$ has at least four connected components because $\Lambda^0{}_{0}\neq 0$ and $\det(\Lambda)\neq 0$. We do not assume the fact that there is precisely four connected components.] It is trivial to check that the kernel is

$$\tag{13} {\rm ker}(\rho)~=~\rho^{-1}({\bf 1}_{s(2)})~=~\{\pm {\bf 1}_{2 \times 2}\}~\cong~\mathbb{Z}_{2}.$$

Let

$$\tag{14} \tilde{\rho}: SL(2,\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}_2 \quad\to\quad SO^{+}(1,2;\mathbb{R})$$

denote the corresponding injective Lie group homomorphism. Thus if we could prove that $\rho$ is surjective/onto, i.e. that the image ${\rm Im}(\rho)\equiv\rho(SL(2,\mathbb{R}))$ is precisely the restricted Lorentz group, cf. Section X below, we would have proved that

> *Theorem.* $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is the double cover of the restricted Lorentz group $SO^{+}(1,2;\mathbb{R})$.

Note that $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is *not* a [universal cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Universal_covers), since we just saw in Section V that

$$\tag{15}\pi_1(SL(2,\mathbb{R}),*)~=~\mathbb{Z}.$$

The universal covering group [$\overline{SL(2,\mathbf{R})}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2%28R%29) is an example of a finite-dimensional Lie group that is *not* a matrix group.

VIII) One may show that the [exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map#Lie_theory) $\exp: sl(2,\mathbb{R}) \longrightarrow SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is *not* surjective

$$\tag{16}{\rm Im}(\exp)
~=~\left\{M\in SL(2,\mathbb{R}) \mid {\rm Tr}(M)> -2\right\} ~\cup~ \left\{-{\bf 1}_{2 \times 2}\right\} ~\subsetneq~ SL(2,\mathbb{R}).$$

It is a small miracle that plus/minus the exponential map $\pm \exp: sl(2,\mathbb{R}) \longrightarrow SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is indeed surjective, which is enough for our purposes, cf. the $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$-kernel (13).

IX) Next let us consider the following Lemma for arbitrary spatial dimensions $d$.

> *Lemma.* Any restricted Lorentz transformation is a product of a pure rotation and a pure boost.

*Proof.* Let us decompose a Lorentz matrix $\Lambda$ into 4 blocks

$$\tag{17} \Lambda ~=~  \begin{bmatrix}a & b^t \cr c &R \end{bmatrix} ,$$

where $a=\Lambda^0{}_0\neq 0$ is a real number; $b$ and $c$ are real $d\times 1$ column vectors; and $R$ is a real $d\times d$ matrix. First argue from $\Lambda^t \eta \Lambda=\eta$, or equivalently from $\Lambda \eta^{-1} \Lambda^t=\eta^{-1}$, that

$$\tag{18} a^2~=~b^tb+1,\qquad  c~=~\frac{Rb}{a}, \qquad  b~=~\frac{R^tc}{a}. $$

Next argue that

$$\tag{19}  B(b)~:=~ \begin{bmatrix} a & b^t \\ b & {\bf 1}_{d\times d}+\frac{bb^t}{a+1} \end{bmatrix}, \qquad a~:=~\sqrt{b^tb+1}~\geq~1, $$

is a Lorentz matrix with an inverse matrix

$$\tag{20}  B(-b)~=~\begin{bmatrix} a & -b^t \\ -b & {\bf 1}_{d\times d}+\frac{bb^t}{a+1} \end{bmatrix}, \qquad B(b)B(-b)~=~{\bf 1}. $$

Such matrices correspond to pure (finite) [boosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation). Use this to prove the Lemma. Hint: The matrix $\Lambda B(-b)$ is on block diagonal form. $\Box$

Also note that we may conjugate a pure boost matrix with a pure rotation matrix to obtain a pure boost matrix in a preferred direction. The Lorentz algebra is

$$\tag{21} so(1,d;\mathbb{R})~=~\left. \left\{  \begin{bmatrix} 0 & b^t \\ b & r \end{bmatrix} \right|  r^t ~=~ -r \right\}. $$

The exponential map is surjective on the set of pure boost:

$$\tag{22} \exp \begin{bmatrix} 0 & b^t \\ b & {\bf 0}_{d\times d} \end{bmatrix}
~=~ B\left(\frac{\sinh|b|}{|b|}b\right), \qquad |b|~:=~\sqrt{b^tb}~\geq~0.$$

Moreover, one may prove that the exponential map $\exp: so(d,\mathbb{R})\to SO(d,\mathbb{R})$ for pure rotations is surjective. For $d=2$ this is trivial.

[Below we only consider the case $d=2$.]

X) Finally, we are able to prove the following Lemma.

> *Lemma.* The group homomorphism $\rho: SL(2,\mathbb{R})\to SO^{+}(1,2;\mathbb{R})$ is [surjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function).

*Proof.* Note that boosts along the $x^3$-axis correspond to

$$\tag{23} g(\beta)~:=~\begin{bmatrix}\exp\left(\frac{\beta}{2}\right)  & 0 \cr 0 &\exp\left(-\frac{\beta}{2}\right) \end{bmatrix}\in SL(2,\mathbb{R}),$$

while rotations correspond to

$$\tag{24} g(\theta)~:=~\begin{bmatrix}\cos\frac{\theta}{2} & \sin\frac{\theta}{2} \cr -\sin\frac{\theta}{2} &\cos\frac{\theta}{2} \end{bmatrix}\in SL(2,\mathbb{R}).$$

Given an arbitrary restricted Lorentz matrix $\Lambda\in SO^+(1,2;\mathbb{R})$, we saw in Section IX that it can be decomposed as (rotation)(boosts along the $x^3$-axis)(rotation'). Hence it can be hit by the $\tilde{\rho}$ group homomorphism

$$\tag{25}  \Lambda ~=~ \tilde{\rho}\left(\tilde{g}(\theta)\tilde{g}(\beta)\tilde{g}(\theta^{\prime})\right).$$

$\Box$

XI) We have the following commutative diagram

$$\tag{26} \begin{array}{rlcrl} &&\tilde{\rho}_{\ast}&& \cr
 &sl(2,\mathbb{R}) & \longrightarrow &so(1,2;\mathbb{R}) \cr
\pm\exp &\downarrow &\circlearrowright&\downarrow&\exp\cr
 &SL(2,\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}_{2} & \longrightarrow &SO^+(1,2;\mathbb{R})\cr
&&\tilde{\rho}&&\end{array} $$

All horizontal arrows are bijections. In particular, the above shows the following theorem.

> *Theorem.* The exponential map $\exp: so(1,2;\mathbb{R}) \to SO^+(1,2;\mathbb{R})$ is surjective.

References:

1. V. Bargmann, *Irreducible Unitary Representations of the Lorentz Group,* Ann. Math. 48 (1947) 568-640. The pdf file is available [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1969129). We mostly use results from p. 589-591.

Comment: Correction to the answer (v8): $\overline{SL(2,\mathbf{R})}$ should be $\overline{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$.

Comment: Related Math.SE post: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1661774/11127

Answer (score 1):

For 1) @Vibert gives you the indications.

For 2) The group $0(1,2)$ - with signatures (+ - -) has 4 disjoint components which can be characterized by :

$$M_1 = Diag (1, 1, 1)$$
$$M_2 = Diag (1, -1, -1)$$
$$M_3 = Diag (-1, 1, 1)$$
$$M_3 = Diag (- 1, -1, -1)$$

$S0(1,2)$ corresponds to matrix of determinant 1, so $S0(1,2)$ has 2 disjoint components ($M_1, M_2$)

$0^+(1,2)$ - which conserve the sign of the 1st coordinate -  has 2 disjoint components ($M_1, M_2$)

$S0^+(2,1)$ -  has 1 component ($M_1$)

$SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is connected (so only 1  component), but it is not simply connected.

So, it is not possible to have a isomorphism between $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $0^+(1,2)$ because the number of disjoint components is different.

We could think about an isomorphism between $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $S0^+(1,2)$, but in fact the isomorphism is between $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $Spin^+(1,2)$, while there is an isomorphism between $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $S0^+(1,2)$, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2(R))

Note that $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, $SU(1,1)$, and $Sp(2,\mathbb{R})$ are isomorphic, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59717/description-of-su1-1/59726#59726) question.

Comment: So the right thing to look for is an isomorphism between $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $SO(1,2):$ can you point me to a proof of that?

Comment: The isomorphism is between $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $S0^+(1,2)$

Comment: You could find a demonstration page 16 of this [ref](http://www.fysik.su.se/~ingemar/SL2.pdf). In this ref, note that $S0_o(1,2)$ is the same thing that $S0^+(1,2)$, and that the $Z_2$  quotient is there because in the formula (32), the result is the same if you choose $-g$ instead of $g$

Comment: Right. This makes perfet sense, and it is the analogous of what is done in 4 dimensions. Still I'm not sure how to prove that $O_+$ leaves the upper cone invariant.

Comment: Right, in 4 dimensions, the isomorphism is between $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and $S0_o(1,3)$.

Comment: In fact, if you look in my answer, you will see that $0^+(1,2)$ is the same thing that $S0(1,2)$, and we know that  $S0(1,2)$ is a subgroup of $0(1,2)$. Note that it is not true with odd spatial dimensions, for instance $0^+(1,3)$ is not the same thing that $S0(1,3)$

Comment: Summarizing: using the connected components argument, we don't have to prove $O_+$ is subgroup, since in this case it is for free; using this same argument and Ron Maimon answer in the duplicate post, we can also conclude that each of the two connected components preserves the upper cone, and thus the full $O_+$ does this job: do you agree?

Comment: Each of the 2 components corresponding to $M_1$ and $M_2$ (in my answer) keep the orientation for the first coordinate (it is clear when looking at the matrices). The full $0^+(1,2) = SO(1,2)$, is a subgroup of $0(1,2)$. Being the the union of these 2 disjoint components which preserve the orientation of the 1st coordinate, obviously the full $0^+(1,2)$ preserve also the orientation of the 1st coordinate.

Comment: For instance, $M_1$ and $M_2$ are special elements of $0^+(1,2)$. And you can check that $M_1 M_1 = M_1$, $M_1 M_2 = M_2$, $M_2 M_1 = M_2$, $M_2 M_2 = M_1$