# From irreducible representations of the Lorentz algebra to irreducible representations of the Lorentz group

Tags: special-relativity, representation-theory, group-representations, lie-algebra, lorentz-symmetry

My lecture notes state that we need to classify all finite-dimensional irreducible representations of the proper, orthochronous Lorentz group in order to formulate a QFT for particles with non-zero spin.

This is done by characterising the Lorentz algebra by the eigenvalues $a (a + 1)$ and $b (b + 1)$ of the square of the operators
$$
\vec{A} = \frac{1}{2} (\vec{J} + i \vec{K}) \\
\vec{B} = \frac{1}{2} (\vec{J} - i \vec{K}) ,
$$
where $\vec{J}$ is the generator of rotation and $\vec{K}$ the generator of boosts.

The corresponding representation of the Lorentz group is then obtained by taking the exponential map of particular operators like $\frac{\vec{\sigma}}{2}, 0$ for $a = \frac{1}{2}, b = 0$.

Can $\vec{A}^2$ an $\vec{B}^2$ be understood as the Casimirs of the Lie algebra or do they have something in common with the concept (I am missing some understanding here)?

How can I guarantee that taking the exponential map of an irreducible representation of the Lie algebra gives me an irreducible representation in the corresponding Lie group?

Comment: I've asked a related question on [math.se] -https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2316362/ - perhaps it is of some help.

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): Are you talking about the restricted Lorentz group/algebra, or its complexification?

Comment: To be honest, I can't tell. We have not dived that deep into group theory in our theoretical particle physics course. I came across this complexification thing, when searching here and on Wikipedia, but wasn't able to wrap my head around it. Please feel free to explain how those things relate!

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_of_a_Lie_group#Lie_group_versus_Lie_algebra_representations) not helpful?

Comment: This answers my second question more or less. What I still don't understand  is the notion of this part: “In general, however, not every representation of the Lie algebra comes from a representation of the group. This fact is, for example, lying behind the distinction between integer spin and half-integer spin in quantum mechanics. ”. This is related to projective representation, if I understand it correctly, but I do not understand the article on them, since (as mentioned above) I am lacking some mathematical background. Could you try to explain this or point to a good reference?

Comment: Two good references for projective representations are Weinberg's *The Quantum Theory of Fields, Vol I, chapter 2*, and Brian C. Hall's *Lie groups, Lie algebras, and Representations: An Elementary Entroduction*. (The first one is not an easy read, but it covers infinite-dimensional representations.) There is also a detailed version of the Wikipedia article on the Lorentz group representations at [Wikiversity](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Group_representations_from_Lie_algebra_representations). It follows Hall's construction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. [Finite-dimensional irreducible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group)

   - (i) [representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation) of the double cover $Spin^+(1,3,\mathbb{R})\cong SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ of the restricted Lorentz group $SO^+(1,3;\mathbb{R})$,
   - (ii) representations of the corresponding Lie algebra $so(1,3;\mathbb{R})$,
   - (iii) [projective representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_representation) of the restricted Lorentz group $SO^+(1,3;\mathbb{R})$,

   are all labelled by two non-negative half-integers $$(a,b)~\in~\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{N}_0 \times\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{N}_0.$$

   See also e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149455/2451) Phys.SE post and links therein.
2. If $a+b~\in~\mathbb{N}_0$ is an integer, it is also a group representation of the restricted Lorentz group $SO^+(1,3;\mathbb{R})$ itself.
3. $A_i$ and $B_i$, $i\in\{1,2,3\},$  are the $3+3=6$ generators of the complexified [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#The_Lie_algebra) $$so(1,3;\mathbb{C})~\cong~sl(2,\mathbb{C})_A\oplus sl(2,\mathbb{C})_B,$$ with quadratic Casimirs $\vec{A}^2$ and $\vec{B}^2$.
4. The exponential map $\exp: so(1,3;\mathbb{R})\to SO^+(1,3;\mathbb{R})$ for the restricted Lorentz group is surjective, cf.  e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160939/2451) Phys.SE post.