# Matrices belonging to restricted Lorentz group $SO^+(1,3)$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, group-theory, lie-algebra

My Professor says that all members of the [restricted Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group) $SO^+(1,3)$ may be written as $e^\Gamma$, where
$$ \Gamma^{\mu}{}_{\nu}=\Lambda^{\mu \rho} \eta_{\rho \nu}.$$
Here $\Lambda$ is an antisymmetric Matrix, and $\eta$ is the standard Minkowski metric [$diag(1,-1,-1,-1)$].
I want to prove a weaker statement. That all matrices of the said form belong to $SO^+(1,3)$.
I have been able to show that they belong to $SO(1,3)$. However, the orthochronous bit is troubling me.
Any help is appreciated.

Progress so far:
$$(\Lambda \eta)^T=-\eta \Lambda$$
$$\implies (e^{\Lambda \eta})^T=e^{-\eta \Lambda}$$
$$\eta e^{-\eta \Lambda} \eta=e^{-\Lambda \eta}$$
$$\eta e^{-\eta \Lambda} \eta e^{\Lambda \eta}=I$$
$$e^{-\eta \Lambda} \eta e^{\Lambda \eta}=\eta$$
$$\implies (e^{\Lambda \eta})^T\eta e^{\Lambda \eta}=\eta.$$

Hence $e^{\Gamma} \in O(1,3)$.
Further, Suppose $\Lambda$ is written as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&\vec{\lambda}\\
-\vec{\lambda}&R\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Where $R$ itself is antisymmetric.
Block Multiplication on the right by $\eta$, gives $\Lambda \eta$ to be,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&-\vec{\lambda}\\
-\vec{\lambda}&-R\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Clearly Trace of $\Lambda \eta$ is 0. Hence $Det(\Lambda \eta)=1$.
Therefore  $e^{\Gamma} \in SO(1,3)$.

Comment: Hint: all such matrices can be continuously connected to the identity by multiplying Gamma by a factor lambda between zero and one. The determinant of these matrices is a continuous function of lambda that equals 1 at zero, and can only equal 1 or -1, and that proves membership in SO(1,3). A similar argument holds for orthochronality, changing the determinant for a suitable function.

Answer (score 1):

Comments to the question (v2):

1. That the [exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_%28Lie_theory%29) $$\exp: o(1,d) ~\to~ O(1,d)$$ has image $$\exp(o(1,d))~\subseteq~ SO^+(1,d)$$ inside the [restriced Lorentz group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Restricted_Lorentz_group) 
   $$ SO^+(1,d)~:=~\{ \Lambda \in SO(1,d) | \Lambda^0{}_0>0 \} $$
   follows from the facts that the [image of a connected set under a continuous map must again be connected](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=image+connected+set+continuous+map+connected), cf. above comment by Emilio Pisanty. (One more hint: No Lorentz matrix $\Lambda$ can have zero determinant $\det(\Lambda)=0$ or zero 00-entry $\Lambda^0{}_0=0$, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36384/2451) Phys.SE post.)
2. The non-trivial fact that the exponential map $$\exp: o(1,d) ~\to~ SO^+(1,d)$$ is [surjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) is discussed in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160939/2451) Phys.SE post.