# Lorentz invariance of the Heaviside function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry

Consider the Heaviside function $\Theta(k^{0})$.

This function is Lorentz invariant if $\text{sign}\ (k^{0})$ is invariant under a Lorentz transformation.

I have been told that only orthochronous Lorentz transformations preserve $\text{sign}\ (k^{0})$ under the condition that $k$ is a time-like vector.

I would like to prove this explicitly, to convince myself of the fact. How do I start?

N.B.: [Lorentz-invariance of step function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/178746/lorentz-invariance-of-step-function) contains a sketch of the proof but it does not contain the complete proof in explicit steps, though.

Comment: The proof is given in [How to prove that proper orthochronous Lorentz transformations form a group?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36384/), though you'll have to think a bit about it.