# Definition of the Lorentz group

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry

This is from Carrol's book, page 13 - 
[image]

This Sort of notation is new to me, and i'm having trouble understanding the claim on the bootom part (second sentence from the end).

1. Does $(\rho,\sigma)= (0,0) \Rightarrow \rho=\sigma=0$?
2. And how can we show that $|\Lambda_{0}^{0'}|\geq 1$?
3. Does it refer to the RHS or the LHS of 1.29?

Also, can anyone give an example to a time reversal? Why don't we allow those?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36384/2451 and links therein.

Comment: is there any simpler or more intuitive explanation?

Comment: 1. Yes. 3. Both. 2. Follow the text and write down explicitly Eq.(1.29) for the case $(\rho,\sigma) =(0,0)$ by expanding the Einstein sum convention. What do you see?

Comment: $-1=\eta_{00}=\Lambda^{\mu'}{}_{0}\Lambda^{\nu'}{}_{0}\eta_{\mu'\nu'}=\sum_{\mu'\nu'}\Lambda^{\mu'}{}_{0}\Lambda^{\nu'}{}_{0}\eta_{\mu'\nu'}=\Lambda^{0}{}_{0}\Lambda^{0}{}_{0}\eta_{00}+\Lambda^{1}{}_{0}\Lambda^{1}{}_{0}\eta_{11'}+\Lambda^{2}{}_{0}\Lambda^{2}{}_{0}\eta_{22}+\Lambda^{3}{}_{0}\Lambda^{3}{}_{0}\eta_{33}$

which means $\left(\Lambda^{0}{}_{0}\right)^{2}=-1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\eta=diag(-1,1,1,1)$ take the zeroth component of $\eta_{\rho \sigma}=\Lambda^{\mu}_{\,\rho} \Lambda^{\nu}_{\,\sigma} \eta_{\mu \nu}$ setting $\rho=\sigma=0$:

$$-1=\eta_{0 0}=\Lambda^{\mu}_{\,0} \Lambda^{\nu}_{\,0} \eta_{\mu \nu}=\Lambda^{0}_{\,0} \Lambda^{0}_{\,0} \eta_{0 0} + \sum_{i=1}^3 \Lambda^{i}_{\,0} \Lambda^{i}_{\,0} \eta_{ii} = -\Lambda^{0}_{\,0} \Lambda^{0}_{\,0} + \sum_{i=1}^3 \Lambda^{i}_{\,0} \Lambda^{i}_{\,0}.$$
Combining the very left and the very right one obtains $$(\Lambda^{0}_{\,0})^2 =\sum_{i=1}^3 ( \Lambda^{i}_{\,0})^2 +1.$$

Hence $|\Lambda^{0}_{\,0}|\geq 1$.